# How do you compare 2 operands of type Date? to sort an array in Swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sorting

In order to sort an array of a custom struct that has bools, integers, and dates. I successfully used the syntax below for a boolean value and it works for the "bride" and "groom" cases. When I attempted to add a sort for 2 Date variables though, I got the error error that:

> "Binary operator '>' cannot be applied to two 'Date?' operands"

I was under the impression that Date values could get compared in a similar fashion with normal **`> < ==`** criteria, but I presume I am getting the error because the values are not unwrapped? If that is correct , I don't think I can do an if let to turn Date? into an unwrapped Date, so I am not sure how I can compare these values.

```
    var sortedImages = [submitted_image]()
    switch sortOption {
    case .brideInPic:
        print("bride")
        sortedImages = Images.sorted(by: {$0.brideInPic && !$1.brideInPic})
        print("sortedImages: \(sortedImages.count), Images: \(Images.count)")
    case .groomInPic:
        print("groom")
        sortedImages = Images.sorted(by: {$0.groomInPic && !$1.groomInPic})
        print("sortedImages: \(sortedImages.count), Images: \(Images.count)")
    case .create_dt:
        print("create")
        sortedImages = Images.sorted(by: {$0.create_dt > $1.create_dt})
    }
```

Comment: Consider to declare the date property non-optional. In practice every image should have a creation date. And this is not Javascript, please use *lowerCamelCased* variable names.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Optionals cannot be compared directly (compare [SE-0121 – Remove Optional Comparison Operators](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0121-remove-optional-comparison-operators.md)). But you can use the nil-coalescing operator `??` to provide a default date for entries without creation date:

```
Images.sorted(by: {$0.create_dt ?? .distantPast > $1.create_dt ?? .distantPast })
```

With [`.distantPast`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/date/1779829-distantpast) the entries without creation date are sorted to the end of the list. With [`.distantFuture`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/date/1779684-distantfuture) they would be sorted to the start of the list.

Comment: Thanks that worked.  You don't by any chance know if you can derive a value?  I have a label for a picture like "Childhood", "High School", "College", "Adult" in my struct.  I want to order by this chronological tag, but I can't order by the value as text or Adult comes before Childhood.  I can always just add a new field to my struct with an integer representation of the label but I was wondering if you knew of a way to derive the order?

Comment: @DanielPatriarca: Your question is not clear to me. Perhaps you want an `enum YourType: Int` so that you can sort on the `rawValue`? Otherwise I suggest to ask a new question where you can describe the problem in more detail.