# How to sort outer array based on inner array value?

Tags: swift

I have an array of tuple, tuple contains array of struct `Bill`

`let billDetails = [(name:String, bills:[Bill])]()`

```
struct Bill {
    var date: Date
}
```

The inner array `bills` is already sorted by the date property. Now I want to sort the outer array based on the inner array's first object's date property.

How to do this without force unwrapping?

`billDetails = billDetails.sorted(by: { $0.bills.first!.date < $1.bills.first!.date })`

Comment: Need to check `$0.bills.first != nil && $.bills.first != nil` isn't?

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56073710/1187415.

Comment: @MartinR If it was Int, I would have used `Int.min` and `Int.max`. Didn't know about `distantPast` and `distantFuture`. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to decide where to put an item if its `bills` is empty. There is really only 2 options, either put them at the start of the array or at the back of the array.

You can use `??` to provide a default value of either `distantFuture` or `distantPast` depending on where you want the empty bills to go.

```
// empty bills last
billDetails.sort(by: { $0.bills.first?.date ?? Date.distantFuture < $1.bills.first?.date ?? Date.distantFuture })
// or empty bills first
billDetails.sort(by: { $0.bills.first?.date ?? Date.distantPast < $1.bills.first?.date ?? Date.distantPast })
```

Comment: Can you give titles for your answers, which puts empty bills at first and which puts last. If I want to remove the items when its bills is empty, It it possible to do without using another filter function?

Comment: @arunsiva edited. You can’t remove stuff from an array with just a sort.

Answer (score 1):

How about the following?

```
billDetails = billDetails.sorted(by: { lhs, rhs in
  guard !lhs.bills.isEmpty || !rhs.bills.isEmpty else {
    return false
  }

  if !lhs.bills.isEmpty, rhs.bills.isEmpty {
    return false
  }

  if lhs.bills.isEmpty, !rhs.bills.isEmpty {
    return true
  }

  return lhs.bills[0].date < rhs.bills[0].date
})
```

Comment: What happens when one element in billDetails contains  empty bills? That one will be the first element after sorting?

Comment: Please check my edit. It should achieve your desired behavior. But you can easily change it if you want to empty bills in the end.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Giving default value seems more simple and readable

Comment: Agreed. But in the case you want to handle the case where both are empty and sort by a secondary field, just edit in the first guard. Anyways, I'm glad you could find your answer! :)