# Sort array of tuples swift

Tags: arrays, swift, tuples

I have an array of tuples in swift:

```
var arrayOfTuples = [(kg: Double, date: Date?)]
```

so it looks like

```
var arrayOfTuples = [(10, 01-03-2020),(11, 01-01-2020)]
```

i want a sorted array on the date, so first date first in array. How can i do that.
The output has to be

```
var arrayOfTuples = [(10, 01-01-2020),(11, 01-02-2020)]
```

I know array.sort() but cant get it to work

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2296801-sort

Comment: If the date of an element in your collection is nil where should it be placed?

Comment: Compare [How do you compare 2 operands of type Date? to sort an array in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56073632/how-do-you-compare-2-operands-of-type-date-to-sort-an-array-in-swift).

Comment: Those are not dates.

Answer (score 0):

This is how to `Sort`:

```
arrayOfTuples.sort { $0.date ?? .distantPast < $1.date ?? .distantPast }
```

Edit: You might want to handle optional dates -> `Date?` differently. I've just given the `distantPast` and `distantFuture` as Leo mentioned to sort them so that they reside at the start.

Comment: this is not a good idea. If the array contains past and future dates the nil values would be sorted in between

Comment: OP would need to define if he wants the ones that are nil to be moved to the start or the end of his collection. This way you could use `.distantPast` or `.distantFuture` accordingly. `sort {$0.date ?? .distantPast < $1.date ?? .distantPast }`

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I din get it, what's the issue? I did try it out on play-grounds.